# Application out of compliance with the Youtube Developer Policy. Why?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

i have sent request to YouTube to get more Quota, they send me email with screenshot.

Email:

> "We have reviewed your quota extension request for project number 49182590595 and have revoked the allocated quota for your API Client as it is out of compliance on the following Youtube API Services - Developer Policy"

where is exactly the problem?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If you check [YouTube API Services Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service) you will find a link to the [YouTube API Services - Developer Policies](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies) you will find that number 9 states exactly that

[image]

You are violating this and there for google has revoked your access.   As a note is is best not to violate google's TOS because once you have done so i have never seen anyone able to get access back.

In the future its a good idea to read and understand the TOS before developing an application.

Comment: thanks for your answer , my app don't play play YouTube videos in background as you see the screenshots is just floating windows . there is a lot of apps in store play YouTube videos in small pop up !

Comment: Unfortunately you seam to be of the opinion that this is something you can defend against.  It is not.  If google says that you are violating their TOS they are within their rights to remove your access.     Just because someone else like you was able to create an app that is against the TOS is not a defense when google finds them they will probably also be locked down, just like you.